# TSQL Using Sequences to insert into table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by, sequence

I am struggling to comprehend this below,

```
INSERT INTO Sales.MyOrders(orderid, custid, empid, orderdate) 
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR Sales.SeqOrderIDs OVER(ORDER BY orderid),
       custid,
       empid,
       orderdate
FROM Sales.Orders
WHERE custid = 1;
```

The book says the

> OVER clause with an ORDER BY list to control the order in which the sequence values are assigned to the result rows

If I can get clarification that would be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [NEXT VALUE FOR (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878370.aspx)

> Generates a sequence number from the specified sequence object.

and

[Sequence Numbers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx)

> A sequence is a user-defined schema-bound object that generates a
>   sequence of numeric values according to the specification with which
>   the sequence was created. The sequence of numeric values is generated
>   in an ascending or descending order at a defined interval and may
>   cycle (repeat) as requested. Sequences, unlike identity columns, are
>   not associated with tables. An application refers to a sequence object
>   to receive its next value. The relationship between sequences and
>   tables is controlled by the application. User applications can
>   reference a sequence object and coordinate the values keys across
>   multiple rows and tables.

This is new functionality in SQL Server 2012 which allows multiple tables to use the same identity sequence, to allow for unique IDs accross different tables.

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1be24/1)

Have a look at the attached DEMO, you will see the effect of how the *autonumber* is used accross tables.

The OVER ORDER BY just ensures that the order of the generated sequence is specified.

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f3f00/2)

The above demo should illustrsate how the sequnce is then assigned based on the ORDER of the original IDs.